# How can I stop url.exists()?

Tags: r, url, web-scraping, download, rcurl

I have a list of PDF URLs, and I want to download these PDFs. However, not all of the URLs are still existing, this is why I check them before by means of the RCurl function `url.exists()`. With some URLs, however, this function is running forever without delivering a result. I can't even stop it with a `withTimeout()` function.

I wrapped `url.exists()` into `withTimeout()`, but the timeout does not work:

```
library(RCurl)
library(R.utils)
url <- "http://www.shangri-la.com/uploadedFiles/corporate/about_us/csr_2011/Shangri-La%20Asia%202010%20Sustainability%20Report.pdf"
withTimeout(url.exists(url), timeout = 15, onTimeout = "warning")
```

The function runs forever, timeout is ignored.

**Thus my questions:**

- Is there any possible check which sorts out this URL before it gets to url.exists()?
- Or is there a possibility to prevent url.exists() from running forever?

Other checks I tried (but which do **not** sort out this URL) are:

```
try(length(getBinaryURL(url))>0) == T
http_status(GET(url))
!class(try(GET(url]))) == "try-error"
```

Comment: I don't use the RCurl package but according to the documentation, you should do this: `url.exists(url, timeout_ms=15)` The problem appears to be that you need the timeout within curl and not within R.

Comment: Was about to post what @Roland said. I'd just add that the correct option is `timeout.ms` (with the dot rather than the underscore).

Comment: Thanks for your valuable contributions :) With the timout.ms option, it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
library(httr)

urls <- c(
  'https://www.deakin.edu.au/current-students/unitguides/UnitGuide.php?year=2015&semester=TRI-1&unit=SLE010', 
  'https://www.deakin.edu.au/current-students/unitguides/UnitGuide.php?year=2015&semester=TRI-2&unit=HMM202',
  'https://www.deakin.edu.au/current-students/unitguides/UnitGuide.php?year=2015&semester=TRI-2&unit=SLE339'
)

sapply(urls, url_success, config(followlocation = 0L), USE.NAMES = FALSE)
```

This functions is analogous to file.exists and determines whether a request for a specific URL responds without error. We make the request but ask the server not to return the body. We just process the header.